# Decimal Prime Number to Binary

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I try to convert decimal prime number to binary format... I've got 2 different working code blocks but I don't how to integrated with them.

Here's my prime number code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int num, sr, num2;
    int isPrime = 1; 
    printf("Prime\t    | Binary\n");
    printf("============================\n");
    for(num=2; num<=100; num++){
        sr = (int) sqrt(num);
        for(num2=2; num2 <= sr; num2++){
            //num2 <== sr to stop the innner loop
            if(num%num2 == 0){
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime){
            printf("%d\t    |\n", num);
            isPrime = 1;
        }else{
            isPrime = 1; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the decimal to binary:

```
int decimalNumber,remainder,quotient;
int binaryNumber[100],i=1,j;
while(quotient!=0){
     binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;
     quotient = quotient / 2;
}

for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
     printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);
```

What I want:

```
Prime       | Binary
=====================
2           | 10
3           | 11
...
```

Comment: Did you consider having a `void print_number_in_binary(int n);` routine

Comment: So let's get this clear, you have to pieces of code, and you want to merge them together?

Comment: @android93 Do you know what a function is?

Comment: @Antonijn unfortunately.. I try to learn.

Comment: @android93 Then perhaps your programming knowledge is insufficient for stack overflow. Consider following a generic C tutorial first, and then have another look at your code. You should figure it out fairly quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can essentially just copy and paste the code to the right place (with a minor change or 2).

```
...
if(isPrime){
   int quotient = num;
   int binaryNumber[100],i=1,j;

   printf("%d\t    |", num);

   while(quotient!=0){
      binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;
      quotient = quotient / 2;
   }

   for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
      printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);

   printf("\n");
   isPrime = 1;
}
...
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/QAjhGT).

But **a function** is probably better. It would look something like:

```
void printBinary(int decimalNumber)
{
    int quotient = decimalNumber;
    int binaryNumber[100],i=1,j;
    while(quotient!=0){
        binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;
        quotient = quotient / 2;
    }

    for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
        printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);
}
```

and you'd call it with

```
printBinary(num);
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/syEYXZ).